# How to access the floating IP in different systems in open stack?

Tags: devstack, openstack-neutron, floating-ip

Installed the openstack in the server. The Host IP given is 192.168.1.2. Created the instance using ubuntu_14 image and also associated the floating IP 192.168.1.234. Enabled TCP and ICMP rules in security group. Installed Apache2 in the instance. I can only access the instance in the browser of server that is 192.168.1.2 and not able to access the floating IP in other devices using the same network. I can access the floating IP through SSH. Can anyone please help me in accessing the IP in other devices?